# Страница отвечающая на запрос проверяя id

Tags: php, javascript

Как должна выглядить php страница, которая будет отвечать на такой вопрос типа true или falseя(можно как то по другому), проверив есть ли в файле spisok.txt данный id или нет.

В файле id написаны в одну строку через запятую!

```
var xmlHttpRequest = (function () {

    var _xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();


    function sendRequest(url) {

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            _xmlHttpRequest.onload = function () {

                resolve(_xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
            };

            _xmlHttpRequest.onerror = function () {

                reject(_xmlHttpRequest.statusText);
            };

            _xmlHttpRequest.open("get", url, true);

            _xmlHttpRequest.send();
        });
    }


    return {

        sendRequest: sendRequest
    }
})();

xmlHttpRequest.sendRequest("http://site.ru/test.php?id=21312").then(function (result) {

    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a.php

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $found = false;

    $file = file_get_contents('spisok.txt');
    $id_list = explode(",", $file);

    foreach($id_list as $i => $value) {
        if($value == $id) {
            $found = true;
        }
    }

    echo $found ? 'true' : 'false';
}
```

script.js

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'a.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send('id=' + 21312);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if(xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // false or true
        }
    }
}
```

spisok.txt

```
1,2,3,4,5,21312,56
```

Comment: Для GET запроса `xhr.open('GET', 'a.php?id=21312', true);`
`xhr.send();`